# Sliders not working in angularjs routing/ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem. 
I build my a project using a customized twitter bootstrap template bought for a few bucks with lots of sliders, pictures and menus.
I developed a simple angularjs app with some routing to my angularjs partial pages including partials/main.htm page consisting only of divs that i moved out of original index.html. 
Routing works fine but it hides the sliders when it loads from partial/main.html file but work fine if I put sliders div in the index page.
I understand the simplest way to fix these is rearrange imports but spending several hours I was not success-full,here is the head part of the index.html. I tried putting some js references in the body without good results.
Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <title> Template Home</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/portal/style.css" />
   <link href="css/portal/setting.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/portal/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/portal/banner_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/portal/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <!-- jQuery, Angular,bootstrap -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src='/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js'></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.bootstrap.newsbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="/lib/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
   <script src="/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Modernizr javascript -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
   <!-- jQuery REVOLUTION Slider  -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Parallax javascript -->
   <script src="js/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js"></script>
   <!-- Initialization of Plugins -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/template.js"></script>
   <!-- Custom Scripts -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Hi @Asad, please share if you resolved this issue, experiencing the same issue.